# wget works for commandline but not in PHP

Tags: php, wget

I'm trying to access some remote web sites within my PHP script, but the script keeps timing out.

It only fails when run on the test web server, but not on the production web server.

The script works just fine when accessing most other URLs, e.g. stackoverflow.com, or www.google.com.

I've tried it with the PHP commands `file_get_contents($url)`, as well as `exec("wget $url"`) and `exec("curl $url")`, all of which fail. Again, most sites work fine, just not the ones I actually want.

I can access the remote sites on the command-line via wget and curl. Even the PHP script works from the command-line! So I know the script works.

The script works when run on our production web server. But it doesn't work when it runs on the test web server.

It appears that there is something peculiar about a GET request from the test server to the remote sites only when comes from Apache, but not the command-line.

How do I diagnose this problem?

Comment: Does the test web server produce any errors? Do you have PHP error displaying enabled? Do you have access to Apache/IIS or PHP logs? Are you able to turn on logging if it already isn't?

Comment: You could test whether it's because of the apache-user's permissions by switching user with `sudo su <apache-user>` (where <apache-user> will probably be `apache` or `www-data`) You can also try using PHP's curl functions, rather than going via `exec`.

Comment: The Apache user is wwwrun on the SUSE linux box.  I can run wget and curl from the command-line for this user, successfully. But the PHP script fails with a 'connection timed out error'.

Comment: What if you add `set_time_limit(0);` at the beginning of the PHP script?

Comment: Experimenting with set_time_limit doesn't help.The problem is not the execution time. The problem is that the connection fails when running the script in Apache.  I can run the script successfully on command-line, quickly, even when I run as the user 'wwwrun'.

Comment: Correction - I get the timeout (for some sites) when I run the script on the command-line as user 'wwwrun', but not as my regular user.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to consider:

- Different system users for command line and web server.
- Proxy server configuration (sometimes done via environment variables).
- Different network (DNS, routing, firewall, etc) configurations for test and production servers.

Comment: 1. I established this point above. When I run from the command line as the web server user, I get the error. Hence it must be some factor related to the web user. What factor could that be?    2. We're not using a proxy server.   3. I'm not sure its a network issue, since I can run it from the commandline as me. I just can't run it as the web server user.